# XML Mapping in Mule

Tags: xml, database, jdbc, mule

I am having an XML message that I pick out from a queue , I need to update the the XML message with the values I get back from a Select statement on a database table.

So initially I save the XML payload to a separate variable. I then issue the database call , save the values in local variables & then reset the payload variable.

```
 //Save Payload
 <set-variable variableName="tempPayload" value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>

  //Database Operation     
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="GetInformation" queryKey="Select Data"> 
            <jdbc-ee:query key="Select Data" value="SELECT address, city, zip,state, country, phone, email,org  FROM Details  WHERE id = "100" />

        </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>  

        <set-variable doc:name="address1" value="#[message.payload[0].address]" variableName="address1"></set-variable> 
        <set-variable doc:name="city" value="#[message.payload[0].city]" variableName="city"></set-variable> 
        <set-variable doc:name="zip" value="#[message.payload[0].zip
]" variableName="zip"></set-variable>
        <set-variable doc:name="state" value="#[message.payload[0].state]" variableName="state"></set-variable>
        <set-variable doc:name="country" value="#[message.payload[0].country]" variableName="country"></set-variable>
        <set-variable doc:name="phone" value="#[message.payload[0].phone]" variableName="phone"></set-variable>
        <set-variable doc:name="email" value="#[message.payload[0].email]" variableName="email"></set-variable>
        <set-variable doc:name="org" value="#[message.payload[0].org]" variableName="org"></set-variable>

        //Reset Payload

        <set-payload value="#[tempPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Now my original payload is in the format:

```
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">
   <TransactionId>376721</TransactionId>
   <TransactionDateTime>2014-01-30T00:00:00</TransactionDateTime>

   <Parties>
      <Party>
         <PartyType>abcd</PartyType>
         <PartyCode></PartyCode>
         <FirstName></FirstName>
         <LastName></LastName>
         <CompanyName></CompanyName>
         <Address1></Address1>
         <CityName></CityName>
         <StateOrProvinceCode></StateOrProvinceCode>
         <PostalCode></PostalCode>
         <CountryCode></CountryCode>
         <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
         <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
      </Party>
      <Party>
         <PartyType>adfa</PartyType>
         <FirstName></FirstName>
         <Address1></Address1>
         <Address2></Address2>
         <CityName></CityName>
         <StateOrProvinceCode></StateOrProvinceCode>
         <PostalCode></PostalCode>
         <CountryCode></CountryCode>
         <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
      </Party>
      <Party>
         <PartyType>XXXXXXX</PartyType>
         <Address/>
         <City/>
         <Zip/>
         <State/>
         <Country/>
         <Phone/>
         <Email/>
         <Org/>
      </Party>
      <Party>

      </Party>
   </Parties>
   <Items>
      <Item>

      </Item>
   </Items>
</Order>
</code>
```

I want to set the values retrieved from the database in the specific party type 'XXXXXXX' & then send the message further for processing.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy Scripting Component with XmlSlurper should do it:

```
//parse
records = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(payload)
//find Party with type XXXXXXXX
party = records.Parties.Party.find { e -> e.PartyType.text().equals('XXXXXXX') }
//set data
party.Zip.replaceBody(flowVars['zip'])
party.City.replaceBody(flowVars['city'])
//rebuild the xml
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
streamingMarkupBuilder=new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
result = XmlUtil.serialize(streamingMarkupBuilder.bind{mkp.yield records})
```

Comment: Anton, I used your component however I am still having issues. For one I am transforming my payload from Byte[] to String & then calling the Scripting component. However I get the Script component fails to get invoked. Also I changed the 'parseText' method to 'parse' to accomodate the incoming String. Do you think these changes are ok or I should try something else? I am concerned about the Script component fails to get invoked.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand you approach. Can you clarify and include possible error messages? XmlSlurper parse() method with String input expects a URI String, so you need to use parseText() with a String payload.

Comment: Never mind Anton, there was a typo in the code I had introduced. Thanks for the immense help it gave the output as I expected. Appreciate it.

Comment: Anton a follow up question I had was is it also possible to remove a Tag from XML based on certain conditions? In the above XML I am searching a tag and adding additional data, but if I wanted to remove a tag completely from XML . Is that doable as well?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There is a method called replaceNode which you can call with on the matching node with an empty closure: replaceNode{}. I suggest you look up some documentation/examples for the Groovy XmlSlurper, and install Groovy Shell, so you can experiment with the methods and traversing interactively.